# Is there any way or plugin for one click url copy in Google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Everytime I have to copy a link in Chrome I need to right click and copy it. Is there any way where I press any key like ctrl, alt, shift and click on the link to directly copy it to clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

So I've checked out the [official page for Mac shortcuts](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165450), for Windows and Linux too, there is NO DEFAULT shortcut for that.

However, I found an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/details), what you can use to bind javascript code or browser action to create custom shortcuts. For this you need some coding skills, but not a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension such as [KeyConfig](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyconfig/okneonigbfnolfkmfgjmaeniipdjkgkl?hl=en) to bind your custom keyboard shortcuts, including an option to `Copy URL`.

If you wish to copy the URL of the current webpage, you are essential performing 3 steps:

1. Click on the Omnibox
2. Select all the text
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or right-click and Copy

A simpler way is to directly `right-click` at the Omibox: Google Chrome will automatically select the URL, and the context-menu with `Copy` is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try Vimium from google store! When pressing "yy" Chrome copies link to clipboard, when pressing "p" url in clipboard is opened in current tab. There's lots of good stuff in Vimium, be sure to check it out

Answer (score 0):

This is old but popping up in searches, so I'll post an updated answer, especially that older ones to not provide exactly what is asked:

Namely, the OP was asking for something like the Firefox addons [Copy Link Button / Copy Frame or Page URL](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-frame-or-page-url/) or [Quick Copy URL](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-copy-url/): ***a ONE-click URL copy button***!

Some addons provide a button to open a new set of options (so the one-click feature is lost; there are [2-click solutions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-page-url-as-plain-te/chnfpahndhcehgdcmnlcahldcopagocp/related) - also [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improved-url-copy/nbkaobaododghmjhkjagellfdahgajlb/related)-, but that we have already without any extension, as seen below); others give page-field or page-link context menu options, etc.

In the end I have founds these:

- [URL Copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-copy/honjkgkhennhamekcgimhdibgcdfbidf/related) - "Copies url with a click!"
- [Copy URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url/ccnghlbhjgabibnajlaklhpikmcannph/related) (no more no less)
- [Copylink](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copylink/hmbglhnodfegeiemefjoejkkmncdobde/related)
- [COPY REACH URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-rich-url/lijjekihhdocbcginjcbipabahcjpjoe/related) - "Just clicking the icon and copying the link of the page as RICH TEXT."
- [Copy Unicode URLs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-unicode-urls/fnbbfiapefhkicjhecnoepbijhanpkjp/related) - "Copy Unicode URLs to clipboard without nasty percent-encodings or Punycode!" (the button representing a Cyrillic letter I guess).
- [URL Shortener & Automatic copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-shortener-automatic-c/fidojahpeagaflnjjbpkpcajhcbghooh/related) - which also shortens the link through [x.gd](https://x.gd.siteindices.com/)
- [Alternative Copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alternative-copy/okpfaahmakpepeoahekhiehomdiikjjg/related) - Copies a shortened shareable link (if the initial link is very long)
- [Copy URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url/fcniaangaighnlfnjgcaonolkiibkdan/related) - should do exactly what we need but it keeps asking for permissions:

[image]

---

As a workaround, there are features already present that don't need supplementary extensions:

- by shortcut in 2 steps : Ctrl-L (to select the url) and Ctrl-C to copy it
- by two clicks: click the *share* button and then click to copy the link:

[image]